# C++: Verify a Windows application is open?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a C++ program that involves opening an application (let's say calculator.exe). I need to be able to test to make sure this application is open. Here's an example of what I mean.

```c
    #include <iostream.h>

    int main()
    {
        system("start calculator");
        if (something)
            cout << "Calculator is running.\n";

        cin.get();
        return 0;
    }
```

What would I need to put in for `something` that tests whether the calculator is open?

Comment: Use an actual API call instead of `system` and you'll get a nice handy handle.

Comment: don't use `iostream.h`, use `iostream`

Comment: Wait a minute!  What are you planning to do with that information.  If you test that the application is running, and the plan to do something knowing that it's open, what will you do if the application is closed between the time you check and the time you act?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it by process name, or you can find it by window title.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

DWORD find_by_process_name(const wchar_t* process_name)
{
    DWORD pid = 0;
    HANDLE hndl = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, 0);
    if (hndl)
    {
        PROCESSENTRY32  process = { sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32) };
        Process32First(hndl, &process);
        do
        {
            if (_wcsicmp(process.szExeFile, process_name) == 0)
            {
                pid = process.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Process32Next(hndl, &process));

        CloseHandle(hndl);
    }

    return pid;
}

int main()
{
    ShellExecuteA(0, "open", "calc.exe", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    if (find_by_process_name(L"calc.exe"))
        std::cout << "calculator is running\n";
    return 0;
}
```