# C++ Process32Next only returns the same process

Tags: c++, winapi, process, kill

I have been trying to develop a C++ lib, with the aim of killing processes only by the name. As described somewhere, I must do a system snap, then list every process (by it's ID), open the process and check if it's filename is the same as the passed to the function, if yes, kill it.

This is my code:
**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "proman.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << "INIT PRUBA" << endl;
    cout << "Trying to kill cmd.exe" << endl;
    const TCHAR* proc = L"cmd.exe";
    killPBN(proc);
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**proman.hpp**

```
#ifndef INC_PROMAN_H
#define INC_PROMAN_H


#include <TCHAR.h> //http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76252/What-are-TCHAR-WCHAR-LPSTR-LPWSTR-LPCTSTR-etc
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "proman.cpp"
//Function prototypes

bool killPBN(const TCHAR *procname); 



#endif
```

**proman.cpp**

```
bool killPBN(const TCHAR *procname)//
{
    //Compiles, but doesnt work, probablemente el fallo este en el compare dentro del for(;;) ==
    //Init some stuff
    TCHAR processPath[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD processId;
    HANDLE tmpHandle = NULL;
    BOOL b;
    
    //Handle to store the snapshot
    HANDLE systemSnap;
    //Initialize to every process dump (no heap nor modules)
    systemSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, NULL);
    if (systemSnap==INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "Can't snap system" << std::endl;
        throw(NULL);
    }
    
    //We have our snapshot, we need to enumerate every process (get its ID)
    //A custom handle to store process data
    PROCESSENTRY32 procHandler;
    //Initialize dwSize so Process32First won't fail
    procHandler.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    //We are ready to call Process32First
    Process32First(systemSnap, &procHandler);
    //Got our first process, now, dump it's ID and ExeFile
    //processPath = procHandler.szExeFile; //Exe Path
    //processId   = procHandler.th32ProcessID; //PID
    
    std::cout << "First Proc: " << procHandler.szExeFile << std::endl;
    
    if (procHandler.szExeFile == procname) //parameter here, use strncompare o como sea
    {
        //Try to open process
        tmpHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, procHandler.th32ProcessID);
        //If opened, kill process
        if (NULL != tmpHandle)
        {   
            std::cout << "Killing: " << procHandler.szExeFile << std::endl;
            TerminateProcess(tmpHandle, 0);
            return 0; 
        }
        //If not opened, throw expection of no admin rights
        else
        {
            //no admin rights?
            //throw(std::out_of_range); 
            std::cout << "Can't Kill Proc: " << procHandler.szExeFile << std::endl;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        while(1==1)
        {
            //The process wasn't the one we were looking for, look next
            b = Process32Next(systemSnap, &procHandler);
            if (b==FALSE)
            {/*throw(proc_not_found);*/
                std::cout << "No more processes" << std::endl;
                break;
            } //no deberia hacer throw, eso solo si hay un error, aqui usar un return!!! si no hay mas procesos
            else
            {
                if (procHandler.szExeFile == procname)
                {
                    tmpHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, TRUE, procHandler.th32ProcessID);
                    if (NULL != tmpHandle)
                    {   
                        TerminateProcess(tmpHandle, 0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout << "Can't kill " << procHandler.szExeFile <<std::endl;
                    //throw(std::out_of_range); //no admin rights?
                }   
            }
        }   
                
    }
    std::cout << " Exit Success";
    

    //Deletes snapshot and tmpHandle
    CloseHandle(systemSnap);
    CloseHandle(tmpHandle);
    return 0;
    
}
```

I know is a bit large code. The idea is looking the first process, if not the desired one, look the next process. But, this is the output:

```
INIT PRUBA
Trying to  kill cmd.exe
First Proc: 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
Can't kill 00C1F510
...
No more processes
 Exit Success
```

As you could see, it seems like the program not reading more than the first process.

Thanks for your time,

EDIT: As you might seem, the szExeFile shall be something like cmd.exe (the exe name) but it's some kind of adress maybe?

EDIT2: Also, notice TCHAR, which is supposed to be replaced by ANSI/UNICODE char/wchart depending on the compiler setup.

Comment: `if (procHandler.szExeFile == procname)` is not doing what you expect -- try to use a debugger and single step through the code

Comment: Your code has loads of mistakes. I can't bring myself to look at this because there are so many.

Comment: @Soren , szExeFile seems to be 00C1F510, while procname is "cmd.exe", obviously is not doing what I expect, since sxExeFile (said by MSND) shall be the exe path or name.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan pointing those errors instead of just saying "It has loads of mistakes" would help much more.

Comment: There's just so many. I can't face it. Especially as you don't take heed when they are pointed out.

Comment: don't I take heed? From msdn: **szExeFile
The name of the executable file for the process** so there's no obvious explanation for it returning what it returns. Again I should say, just saying "there's just so many" is absolutely not help, best do not comment.

Comment: I think your project is in UNICODE (as it should be), you should try `wcout << wide_string << "\n"` instead. Use `strcmp` to compare ANSI strings. Use `wcscmp` for wide strings. See this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29740268/4603670)

Comment: See that comment in your code `use strncompare o como sea`? It's important. You can't compare strings like you're trying to do.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani it has worked like a charm :). What I didn't know was that the operator "==" works as ANSI by default. Thank you very much!

Comment: First comment points out that == is wrong. It's even written in a comment in your own code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified by @BarmakShemirani , I shall use Unicode function as wcout or wcscmp.
Thanks.

Comment: That's wrong if you are going to use TCHAR. You should not use TCHAR. Use Unicode.

Comment: To clarify, you should replace `TCHAR` with either `WCHAR` or `wchar_t`.

Comment: @HarryJohnston so, for a program with unicode support I shall use WCHAR / wchar_t and unicode functions, and for a standard non unicode just use char and normal functions? Thanks.

Comment: @PedroJavierFernández: it isn't really quite that simple.  You should *always* build in Unicode mode, and *almost* always use `wchar_t` for Win32 API functions.  Whether your program supports Unicode in, e.g., whatever data files it uses, and if so how you should encode it internally, is an entirely separate question.  You can always convert between your internal encoding and UTF-16 as necessary.  (One caveat: if you need to deal with filenames robustly, e.g., if you're writing a file system utility, you need to leave the filenames in UTF-16, as converting them may lose information.)